# Updating geo coordinates

Tags: c#, parsing, converting, geospatial

An error in a live environment was detected when trying to convert string geo coordinates into a `double`.

The current culture (hu-HU) uses **comma** instead of point for the decimals and that produced an exception when trying to parse `Double.Parse(47,545874)`
That's why I'm using `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` and the reason to wrap the conversion up in a try/catch statement.

Is there a better way to handle these exceptions?

```
public void UpdateJobGeoCoordinates(Job job)
{
    var address = _kernel.GetKernel();

    var gpsCoordinate = _locator.GetGpsCoordinates(address);

    try
    {
        job.Lat = Double.Parse(gpsCoordinate.Item1, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        job.Lng = Double.Parse(gpsCoordinate.Item2, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
    catch (FormatException)
    {
        ResetCoordinates(job);
        Logger.Warn("Geo location issue for Job [{0}] , Format error when convert '{1}', '{2}' to a Double.", job.ERPServiceOrderId, gpsCoordinate.Item1, gpsCoordinate.Item2);
    }
    catch (OverflowException)
    {
        ResetCoordinates(job);
        Logger.Warn("Geo location issue for Job [{0}] , Overflow when convert '{1}', '{2}' to a Double.", job.ERPServiceOrderId, gpsCoordinate.Item1, gpsCoordinate.Item2);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ResetCoordinates(job);
        Logger.Warn("Geo location issue for Job [{0}] , Exception message: {1}", job.ERPServiceOrderId, ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide more background with your code to allow for a decent review? What's it's purpose, how is it used, etc.

Comment: Why don't you use [Double.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: If `_locator` always returns `Item1` and `Item2` (Tuple?) formatted with the invariant culture number format info rules then you should parse by those rules too (as you are doing). `TryParse` could help if `_locator` can return invalid doubles.

Comment: Thanks @Jamal for your changes. My only concern is about the original purpose of my question; It's not just about "updating geo coordinates", it's more about parsing values and capture possible exceptions. I wonder if the title fits with that. Looking forward for your thoughts.

Comment: @BCdotWEB, I don't use TryParse because I want to log different messages depending on the type of exception. How could I do this more effectively if I would need to run this code in more places of my solution?

Comment: @RobH I don't use TryParse because I want to log different messages depending on the type of exception. How could I do this more effectively if I would need to run this code in more places of my solution?

Comment: @t: You're free to revise the title as needed, as long as it still conveys the purpose of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what it's worth I think you've over complicated this. It seems to me that you care if you succeed or not and then want to pass as much information on to someone who can figure out what went wrong. The only 2 lines that are in the try block are parsing to doubles so just catch `Exception` and beef up the information included.

```
public void UpdateJobGeoCoordinates(Job job)
{
    var address = _kernel.GetKernel();

    var gpsCoordinate = _locator.GetGpsCoordinates(address);

    try
    {
        job.Lat = Double.Parse(gpsCoordinate.Item1, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        job.Lng = Double.Parse(gpsCoordinate.Item2, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ResetCoordinates(job);
        Logger.Warn("Geo location issue for Job [{0}] , Exception details: {1}", job.ERPServiceOrderId, ex);
    }
}
```

Note that `Exception.ToString()` is **so much more useful** than just the message.

You'll get the type of the exception, the message and the stack trace.